# How to add comma to a number in the text in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a project that create report automatically according to inport values. In sheet2 I have input data like `C10=1000`,`C11=150000` and I want at the sheet1 as `C4= 1,000.00 MWh` and `C5= 150,000 Dollar` and I want the numbers as bold.
I write a code like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Range1, Range2
Set Range1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C10")
Set Range2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C11")
Application.EnableEvents = False
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C4") = Range1.Value & " MWh"
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C5") = Range2.Value &" Dollar"
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C4")
 .Characters(InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C4").Value, Range1), Len(CStr(Range1))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
 End With
 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C5")
 .Characters(InStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value, Range2), Len(CStr(Range2))).Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
 End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

But I am getting the results correctly but I cant figure out how to add commas between the digits I tried `.NumberFormat` but It didn't work because it is not in the correct format.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 ""Mwh"""
```

and the value needs to be numeric

```
.Value = 1000
```

Then it will show like

```
1,000.00 Mwh
```

in your cell.

Comment: Surely with correct units it should be MWh ?

Comment: @SolarMike and probably `Dollar` instead of `Dolar` refering to `Range2.Value &" Dolar"` of the question.

Comment: Hey thanks,I will managed the seperate the numbers but all cell turned to bold now!